# Casting zero padded numeric strings to integers

Tags: php

I am padding integers for barcodes with leading zeros so they have same number of characters, for example:

```
1    -> 00000001 
12   -> 00000012
1044 -> 00001044
```

`00000001` is numeric and when casting to an integer it is `1`.

Will this work as expected for **all** integers?

Comment: I don't get it, what's your question?

Comment: You should give us a snippet of code and what you expect the results to be so we can help you solve a problem (if there is one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Careful, numbers starting with 0 are treated as base 8 in PHP

```
>> var_dump(011);
int(9)
```

however explicit casting string to int seems to be safe

```
>> var_dump((int)'011');
int(11)
```

You did not say anything where you're going to be storing these numbers, but in case it will be a database, here's some advice regarding datatype:

Barcode numbers are not (despite the name) numbers.  Same goes for fax numbers, social security numbers, etc. You should not store these as numeric data (for example using MySQL's INT or DECIMAL) datatype. Instead use textual datypes (like CHAR or VARCHAR)

Answer (score 0):

> Will this work as expected for all ints?

That depends on what you expect. Left-padding with zeros will never change the value. Regardless of the number, you can add any number of zeros to the left of the string and it will always be numeric, and it will always cast to the same integer.

```
(int)"01" == 1
(int)"0001" == 1
(int)"000000001" == 1
```

etc.

Comment: @Mchl I thought it was pretty clear the question was about zero-padding strings, since he mentions `is_numeric`, and `(int)"0000000009" == 9`, but I updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you treat it as a string PHP will interpret 00000001 as simply the integer 1. If you want to treat your barcodes as a string, take care to cast them correctly because PHP might interpret them as integers due to [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Comment: If not a string, 00000001 is treated as the integer 1 *in base 8*, so if those 0s precede different values, the result will not be as expected.

Comment: I meant something along the lines of `0 + "000001"` which wouldn't be treated as base 8 unlike `0 + 000001` which would.